# React useMemo dependency loop with state and onChange

Tags: reactjs

In the code below `FormExample` is being rendered. `Form` is a is a wrapper for `SampleTextField`s  and handles changes and state for all child fields. I'm trying to use `useMemo` so that a change in one field does not re-render the other field.

The problem is that the `handleChange` function is cached with its `state` scope so if I change the first field, and then edit the second the state is overwritten with the old value of the first field.

I can add wrap handleChange in `useCallback` but it just creates the same problem with the onChange that it references.

I've also tried adding handleChange to the dependency array for useMemo, but because a new instance of handleChange is created on each state change (because of the re-render) it's the same as not having useMemo.

Is there a pattern I can use to solve this?

```
import {TextField} from '@material-ui/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import {useContext, useState} from 'react';

const FormContext = React.createContext<any>({});
const Form = ({state, onChange, children}: any) => {

  const handleChange = (name: any, val: any) => {
    onChange({...state, [name]: val});
  }

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{state, handleChange}}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}

const SampleTextField = ({name}: any) => {
  const {state, handleChange} = useContext(FormContext);
  const value = state[name]

  return React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <TextField name={name} value={value} onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}/>
    );
  }, [value]);
}

const FormExample = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({text1: "", text2: ""});

  return (
    <Form state={state} onChange={setState}>
      <SampleTextField name="text1"/>
      <br/><br/>
      <SampleTextField name="text2"/>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default FormExample;
```

Comment: "I'm trying to use useMemo so that a change in one field does not re-render the other field." Thats not how it works, if you cause re-render all props are updated.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for managing form state and re-rendering efficiently. Not an answer to your question but could help out if you decide to use it. You'd basically replace the useState in the FormExample component with useForm and add refs to each of your text fields, then the rest would be handled for you. Also, if you're making a form, it's best to use the <form> HTML tag as a container. Hope you get it all sorted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useCallback` to make your `handleChange` reference stable.
Note how I use the function form of `setState` that accepts the current state as the first argument

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import * as React from "react";
import { useContext, useState, useMemo, useCallback, createContext } from "react";

const FormContext = createContext<any>({});
const Form = ({ state, onChange, children }: any) => {
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (name: any, val: any) => {
      onChange((state) => ({ ...state, [name]: val }));
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  const context = useMemo(
    () => ({
      state,
      handleChange,
    }),
    [state, handleChange]
  );

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

const SampleTextField = ({ name }: any) => {
  const { state, handleChange } = useContext(FormContext);
  const value = state[name];

  return useMemo(
    () => (
      <TextField
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
      />
    ),
    [value, handleChange]
  );
};

const FormExample = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ text1: "", text2: "" });

  return (
    <Form state={state} onChange={setState}>
      <SampleTextField name="text1" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <SampleTextField name="text2" />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default FormExample;
```